# How To Link icon-linkedin to Linkedin profile page?

Tags: php, css, html

I have html website. in this Website added Profile Page . Profile  have Socila Icon .  i have added Linkdin page in my Profile page Like

```
  <a href="#" class="social-icon si-rounded si-small si-linkedin">
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
 </a>
```

how To make Icon Clickable to Redirect Linkdin page Profile pag?

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `#` in your `<a href="#" ...` with the URL for your profile page.

Answer (score 1):

Place the URL of your LinkedIn profile in the `href` of `<a>`.

```
<a href="https://linkedin.com/your/profile/url" class="social-icon si-rounded si-small si-linkedin">
  <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="https://linkedin.com/your/profile/url" class="social-icon si-rounded si-small si-linkedin">
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
 </a>
```

Your Code is Funtastic But You Not Give Link Please Give a Link Look Like me

Answer (score 1):

replace the # symbol in your **< a href="#" class="social-icon si-rounded si-small si-linkedin" >** attribute tag with the URL of the Facebook account/page.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <a href="https://in.linkedin.com/in/raru-chempazhanthy-43549623" class="social-icon si-rounded si-small si-linkedin" target="_blank">
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
    <i class="icon-linkedin"></i>
 </a>
```

Here this will open a new tab, where the linkedin profile is shown. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right, you just need to set the `href` of your link (`a`), to the url of your page, ex `<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bill-nye-science-guy-9488063b" class="social-icon si-rounded si-small si-linkedin">`

Also, you have 2 images inside of the link, so unless it's like that for a reason I would recommend deleting one of the `<i class="icon-linkedin"></i>`'s

Read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) for more info on links.